# How to display output in tree-type JSON SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Good day.
I am trying to show a query in JSON but in tree type.
As follows:
Desired output.

[image]

I have the following query where I generate the head node and the key or link, this is my query.

```
    Select --value, 
        --c.IDEMPRESA,
  rtrim(c.JERARQUIA) as JERARQUIA,
  RTRIM(c.IDCONSUMIDOR) as IDCONSUMIDOR, 
  RTRIM(c.DESCRIPCION) DESCRIPCION,
  [KEY]
  
  from consumidor c
```

I attach the result of this query https://dbfiddle.uk/Vi3hP6k6

I have found that to output in JSON format in sql server, the following statement is used.

**FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES**

But I don't know where this line of code should go. Any suggestions on how I can have the output in tree-type JSON?

Comment: And where is the sample data for this query?

Comment: here https://dbfiddle.uk/Vi3hP6k6

Comment: update the query, in the table the relationship field is [key], what I want to obtain from that table is, for example, FATHER - SON - SUB CHILD type tree, I understand that for json type outputs it is the following command FOR JSON PATH , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's very difficult to recursively aggregate in SQL Server.

The easiest method is to just use a scalar function which recurses.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetJson (@ParentKey varchar(512))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS BEGIN

RETURN ISNULL((
    Select --value, 
          --c.IDEMPRESA,
      rtrim(c.JERARQUIA) as JERARQUIA,
      RTRIM(c.IDCONSUMIDOR) as IDCONSUMIDOR, 
      RTRIM(c.DESCRIPCION) DESCRIPCION,
      [KEY],
      items = JSON_QUERY(dbo.GetJson(c.JERARQUIA))
    from dbo.consumidor c
    WHERE [KEY] = @ParentKey
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
), N'[]');

END;
```

Then just begin with the parent or root ID (for some reason it's a space in your case).

```
SELECT dbo.GetJson(' ');
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/7a4fiE6L)

Comment: Okay, I just checked and it meets what is required, thanks with this example it helps me continue investigating.